# How to using regular expressions (regex) to modify all occurrences of a string that follow another string (Notepad++ macro)?

Tags: regex, replace, macros, notepad++, regexp-replace

In the following minimal reproducible example, I want to make all the words in section `[bar]` lowercase:

```
[foo]
foo1=Hello World
[bar]
bar1=Hello World
bar2=Worldly Hello
```

The desired output is:

```
[foo]
foo1=Hello World
[bar]
bar1=hello world
bar2=worldly hello
```

To do this, I use the regular expression (regex) `(.*?\[bar\].*?)([A-Z])` with a replacement string of `$1\L$2`.

In Notepad++, I enable regex in the Find & Replace dialog box and also enable the `Match case` and `. matches newline` options.

Doing this, performing a `Replace` operation works as expected.  I can then repeatedly hit the `Replace` button in Notepad++ over and over until reaching `EOF` to get the job done.

So now that this works, I want to create a reusable Notepad++ macro to end the tedium and perform the operation on the entire file.

My first idea was to simply use `Replace All`, but that won't work because the regex caret does not get reset after each replace operation when using `Replace All`.

How can my regex be improved to replace all `[bar]` section strings with lowercase values and have it work within a Notepad++ macro?

If it's not possible to improve my regex, I am willing to use another Notepad++ macro technique to perform this task.

---

The following is intended as context, and isn't required reading.  Once I understand how to do the above, I can adapt what I learn to the following more complex case.  But if you prefer to focus on this more complex case, that's great too.

*I greatly simplified things for the example above.  In my actual input files, there are multiple `[sections]` before and after the `[bar]` section.  Also, I'm only wanting to apply lowercase to the first letter of all words that are not the first word in a string.  That said, I have working code to accomplish all that, so if I get the greatly simplified example (above) working within a macro, I should have no problem adapting it for the much more complex real world case.*

*If you're interested in the more complex real world case, here is example input:*

```
[foo]
foo1=Hello World
[bar]
bar1=Hello World
bar2=Worldly Hello
bar3=Worldly-Hello
bar4=worldly+Hello
[baz]
baz1=Hello World
```

*are here is the desired output:*

```
[foo]
foo1=Hello World
[bar]
bar1=Hello world
bar2=Worldly hello
bar3=Worldly-hello
bar4=worldly+hello
[baz]
baz1=Hello World
```

Comment: It would help your question to also show what the expected output is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Also added the more complex real world case with sample inputs and outputs if you're interested.

Comment: Your second example input and output appear identical to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what to tell you.  Perhaps new glasses?  Run a `diff` to see the differences?

Comment: The 2 texts at the end of your question are identical.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assure you 100% that you are mistaken.  Look at the HTML code of this page if you need to.  Save the appropriate sections of the source code and run a `diff`.

Comment: If the individual who flagged this question as "needs more details" would please add a comment as to what specific details they think are missing, that would be helpful.  This question is *very* detailed and specific.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket There is one unclear thing about your expected outputs. You say you expect `bar1=hello world` and `bar2=worldly hello` in the first example, but then you say the first word should stay in uppercase (what if it is in lowercase?) and the expected output is now `bar1=Hello world` and `bar2=Worldly hello`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Correct.  I hesitated to include the complex case in the italicized area that provide additional context.  ***For this answer, all I need is the simple case at the top.***  The bottom italicized text just provides context of how I'll be integrating the answer into a more complex system.  I'm wanted to focus on a minimal reproducible example of the primary issue (provided at the top) instead of having people trying to work through the complexities of the real world case (provided at the bottom).  I'll add a few words that the bottom is just for context.

Comment: Ok, please add this clarification, but both things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, there are several quirks that make such replacements harder than in other comparable environments.

You can match all *words* after `[bar]` section header and after each word followed with `=` using

**Find What**: `(?:\G(?!^)|^\[bar])(?:\s*\R\w+=|[^\w\r\n]+)\K\w+`
**Replace With**: `\L$0`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AARuv/3) & settings screenshot:

[image]

**Regex details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^\[bar])` - either of the two: the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) `[bar]` word (`\[bar]`) at the start of a line (`^`)
- `(?:\s*\R\w+=|[^\w\r\n]+)` - zero or more whitespaces, a line break sequence, one or more word chars, `=` (`\s*\R\w+=`), or (`|`) any one or more chars other than word chars, CR and LF (`[^\w\r\n]+`)
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far into the overall match memory buffer
- `\w+` - one or more word chars (`$0` points to this value).

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much.  I need to study your answer carefully and experiment with it, but I think this is exactly what I wanted.  If you have time to break down the regex and explain a little about each section, that will be most helpful.  Thank you again.

Comment: LOL.  Great minds think alike.  ;)  While I was writing a comment, you were editing your answer to provide exactly what my comment was requesting.  Thank you.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Ok, on second thought, it can be even further simplified to `(?:\G(?!^)|^\[bar])(?:\s*\R\w+=|[^\w\r\n]+)\K\w+`

Comment: Ah! I see what you are doing.  The two places where I was having trouble: (1) is `\G(?!^)` always the end of the previous match?  (2) What reference did you use to learn that `\K` is available for use in the Notepad++ regex engine?

Comment: Also, I read quite a bit about regex recursion before posting my question because I thought perhaps I could use it.  My initial read of your answer is that it does not technically use recursion.  Would you agree?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket In Notepad++, that [uses Boost regex engine](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions), [`\K` is supported](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.keeping_back_some_text). The pattern does not use recursion, nor regex subroutines.

Comment: I now have the Boost engine documentation bookmarked.  Thank you so much.  Also thanks for confirming that my understanding regarding recursion is correct.  I have started to adapt your answer to the more complex cases illustrated at the bottom of my question.  If you enjoy this sort of thing (I do... it's like a complex puzzle), feel free to attempt making a regex to handle the more complex cases, and we can compare our solutions.  I edited the example a tiny bit to handle your initial question regarding initial-word casing.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I think all you need is to optionally match the first word after `=`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AARuv/5).

Comment: Yes.  I have it real close now.  The spec is very long for what is allowed/disallowed, so I need to do some more tweaking, but I have it real close.  Thank you again.

Comment: As I examined your regex, I had another question, but it was too long for a comment, and likely worthy of its own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416848/in-regex-regular-expressions-is-escaping-a-closing-square-brace-needed-wh

Comment: I have been carefully studying your regex, and I'm wondering: How does it know to stop before hitting `[baz]`.  I think it is `[^\w\r\n]+`.  Am I correct?  Can you explain this a little more in this context? `[^\w\r\n]+` by itself is obvious, but I'm trying to understand its function in the larger context.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket It does not need that. The regex above matches lines after `[bar]` that can only start with a word + `=`. Since `[baz]` line cannot be matched, matching will stop right there.